# Usar um TextField para descrever um caminho a ser salvo os arquivos

Tags: c#, path

Bom dia pessoal, eu estou tentando criar um sistema que ao eu digitar um nome num textfield ele criaria uma pasta com este nome e adicionaria o arquivo dentro da pasta.

A parte de adicionar o arquivo esta correta, necessito saber como fazer para que crie a pasta.

Sou bem leigo em programação ainda, vou mandar uma linha como exemplo:

```
File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(projectPath,@"novapasta.Domain\Entities\" + varPath + "\\" + entityName + ".cs"), Template);
```

o caminho ficaria no txtPath

Comment: Que linguagem? Que tipo de aplicação? Qual a dúvida que está tendo?

Comment: É C# e a minha dúvida é como eu faço para que o sistema "crie" essa pasta, que eu digitaria no textfield Path (que eu ja transformei em variável).

Mas não faço a mínima ideia de como faria isso.

Comment: Seria interessante então você editar a pergunta, adiciontar a tag da linguagem e essas informações adicionais, a pergunta está confusa da forma como foi postada;.

Comment: ok, primeira vez que usei aqui.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Use o método `Directory.CreateDirectory`. Ele irá criar todos os diretórios e subdiretórios necessários, a menos que eles existam, conforme documentação.

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path
>   unless they already exist.

O método abaixo irá criar as pastas *temp* e *files* dentro do disco C.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\temp\files");
```

Para criar um arquivo num diretório específico, independente dele existir ou não, você pode utilizar algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public void EscreverNoArquivo(string path, string filename, string content)
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText($"{path}\\{filename}", content);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static bool CreateFolder(string folder)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(folder)) return true;
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz algo parecido porém ele tinha sucesso apenas se a pasta já existisse, se a pasta não existisse ele não cria e diz que a pasta não existe.

Veja o que fiz de errado por favor

    `String subPath = txtPath.Text;
            if (!Directory.Exists(subPath))
            {
                
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);
            }`

Comment: o codigo parece correto, teria que verificar se a string subPath esta correta. Ou se é o caminho até um arquivo. `System.IO.Path.HasExtension(String path)` retorna true se tiver extensão, ou false se não, deve ajudar na hora de verificar se o path é realmente uma pasta ou arquivo.

Comment: Se eu usasse o seu código, como eu adiciono o texto da minha variável para o nome do folder?

Comment: Acho que não entendi a sua pergunta. Mas se for o que eu entendi então só precisa chamar o método `CreateFolder(suavariavel);`. Uma possibilidade para o erro que você descreveu na primeira pergunta, é se você mandar criar uma pasta direto no diretório raiz. Algo como `C:\teste` seria impedido pelo Windows. Para ser possível você teria que ceder direito de administrador para o programa.

Comment: Primeiramente você está fazendo extremo mau uso do **`try-catch`**. Você não precisa verificar se o diretório existe antes de criá-lo, se ele já existir, nada vai acontecer. Por consequência, toda essa função é desnecessária e prolixa.

Comment: @jbueno Na verdade isso depende do contexto. O código dessa resposta é o mais performático e thread-safe que poderia ser criado usando apenas o .Net. Usar somente o `if` faria o conjunto não ser thread-safe, usar apenas o `try/catch` traria perda de performance toda vez que o diretório de fato existir: um loop em torno da chamada desse método com milhares de exceções sendo lançadas seria bem ruim se performance for uma consideração.